# Monadic substitution under binders

Tags: monads, substitution, agda, parametric-polymorphism

In the following Agda code, I have a term language based on de Bruijn indices. I can define substitution over terms in the usual de Bruijn indices way, using renaming to allow the substitution to proceed under a binder.

```
module Temp where

data Type : Set where
   unit : Type
   _⇾_ : Type → Type → Type

-- A context is a snoc-list of types.
data Cxt : Set where
   ε : Cxt
   _∷_ : Cxt → Type → Cxt

-- Context membership.
data _∈_ (τ : Type) : Cxt → Set where
   here : ∀ {Γ} → τ ∈ Γ ∷ τ
   there : ∀ {Γ τ′} → τ ∈ Γ → τ ∈ Γ ∷ τ′
infix 3 _∈_

data Term (Γ : Cxt) : Type → Set where
   var : ∀ {τ} → τ ∈ Γ → Term Γ τ
   〈〉 : Term Γ unit
   fun : ∀ {τ₁ τ₂} → Term (Γ ∷ τ₁) τ₂ → Term Γ (τ₁ ⇾ τ₂)

-- A renaming from Γ to Γ′.
Ren : Cxt → Cxt → Set
Ren Γ Γ′ = ∀ {τ} → τ ∈ Γ → τ ∈ Γ′

extend′ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ τ′} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Ren (Γ ∷ τ′) (Γ′  ∷ τ′)
extend′ f here = here
extend′ f (there x) = there (f x)

-- Apply a renaming to a term.
_*′_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Cxt} {τ} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Term Γ τ → Term Γ′ τ
f *′ var x = var (f x)
f *′ 〈〉 = 〈〉
f *′ fun e = fun (extend′ f *′ e)

-- A substitution from Γ to Γ′.
Sub : Cxt → Cxt → Set
Sub Γ Γ′ = ∀ {τ} → τ ∈ Γ → Term Γ′ τ

extend : ∀ {Γ Γ′ τ} → Sub Γ Γ′ → Sub (Γ ∷ τ) (Γ′ ∷ τ)
extend θ here = var here
extend θ (there x) = there *′ θ x

-- Apply a substitution to a term.
_*_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Cxt} {τ} → Sub Γ Γ′ → Term Γ τ → Term Γ′ τ
θ * var x = θ x
θ * 〈〉 = 〈〉
θ * fun a = fun (extend θ * a)
```

What I would like to do now is generalise the type of `Term` into a polymorphic variant, so that I can define a monadic `〉〉=` operation and express substitution using that. Here's naive attempt:

```
data Term (A : Cxt → Type → Set) (Γ : Cxt) : Type → Set where
   var : ∀ {τ} → A Γ τ → Term A Γ τ
   〈〉 : Term A Γ unit
   fun : ∀ {τ₁ τ₂} → Term A (Γ ∷ τ₁) τ₂ → Term A Γ (τ₁ ⇾ τ₂)

Sub : (Cxt → Type → Set) → Cxt → Cxt → Set
Sub A Γ Γ′ = ∀ {τ} → A Γ τ → Term A Γ′ τ

extend : ∀ {A : Cxt → Type → Set} {Γ Γ′ τ} → Sub A Γ Γ′ → Sub A (Γ ∷ τ) (Γ′ ∷ τ)
extend θ = {!!}

_〉〉=_ : ∀ {A : Cxt → Type → Set} {Γ Γ′ : Cxt} {τ} → 
       Term A Γ τ → Sub A Γ Γ′ → Term A Γ′ τ
var x 〉〉= θ = θ x
〈〉 〉〉= θ = 〈〉
fun a 〉〉= θ = fun (a 〉〉= extend θ)
```

The problem here is that I no longer know how to define `extend` (which shifts a substitution into a deeper context), because a substitution is a more abstract beast.

Here's something closer, based on the paper [Names for Free](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~bernardy/NamesForFree.pdf) by Bernardy and Pouillard:

```
module Temp2 where

open import Data.Unit

data _▹_ (A : Set) (V : Set) : Set where
   here : V → A ▹ V
   there : A → A ▹ V

data Term (A : Set) : Set where
   var : A → Term A
   〈〉 : Term A
   fun : Term (A ▹ ⊤) → Term A

Ren : Set → Set → Set
Ren Γ Γ′ = Γ → Γ′

extend′ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ V : Set} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Ren (Γ ▹ V) (Γ′ ▹ V)
extend′ f (here x) = here x
extend′ f (there x) = there (f x)

Sub : Set → Set → Set
Sub Γ Γ′ = Γ → Term Γ′

_<$>_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Set} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Term Γ → Term Γ′
f <$> var x = var (f x)
f <$> 〈〉 = 〈〉
f <$> fun e = fun (extend′ f <$> e)

extend : ∀ {Γ Γ′ V : Set} → Sub Γ Γ′ → Sub (Γ ▹ V) (Γ′ ▹ V)
extend θ (here x) = var (here x)
extend θ (there x) = there <$> θ x

_〉〉=_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Set} → Term Γ → Sub Γ Γ′ → Term Γ′
var x 〉〉= θ = θ x
〈〉 〉〉= θ = 〈〉
fun a 〉〉= θ = fun (a 〉〉= extend θ)
```

The idea here is to model the idea of context extension in an explicitly abstract way, allowing `extend` to be defined for renamings and substitutions even in the polymorphic setting.

Unfortunately, I seem to be too stupid to understand how to extend this approach so that terms are parameterised by a `Type`, as they are in my first attempt above. I would like to end up with 〉〉= having (approximately) the following type:

```
_〉〉=_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Set} {τ} → Term Γ τ → (Sub Γ Γ′) → Term Γ′ τ
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For a couple of seconds I thought I was lost on Mathematics.

Comment: `` you know something's wrong when you use characters that even your browser cannot display...

Comment: I've had this problem before, unfortunately my browser seems to be able to display all the characters fine! Where are you seeing missing chars?

Comment: Ah, just spotted it :) Thanks. Fixed, and also dropped the subscript on :: which has caused problems in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps?  The important thing is how you represent variables. The answer is that in a typed setting, variables need to be indexed by a type. If you make that change, everything more or less follows...

```
module Temp2 where

open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

data Type : Set where
   unit : Type
   _⟶_ : Type → Type → Type

data _▹_ (A : Type → Set) (V : Type → Set) (t : Type) : Set where
   here : V t → (A ▹ V) t
   there : A t → (A ▹ V) t

data Term (A : Type → Set) : Type → Set where
   var : ∀ {t} → A t → Term A t
   〈〉 : Term A unit
   fun : ∀ {t : Type} {T : Type} → Term (A ▹ (_≡_ T)) t → Term A (T ⟶ t)

Ren : (Type → Set) → (Type → Set) → Set
Ren Γ Γ′ = ∀ {t} → Γ t → Γ′ t

extend′ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ V : Type → Set} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Ren (Γ ▹ V) (Γ′ ▹ V)
extend′ f (here x) = here x
extend′ f (there x) = there (f x)

Sub : (Type → Set) → (Type → Set) → Set
Sub Γ Γ′ = ∀ {t} → Γ t → Term Γ′ t

_<$>_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Type → Set} {t} → Ren Γ Γ′ → Term Γ t → Term Γ′ t
f <$> var x = var (f x)
f <$> 〈〉 = 〈〉
f <$> fun e = fun (extend′ f <$> e)

extend : ∀ {Γ Γ′ V : Type → Set} → Sub Γ Γ′ → Sub (Γ ▹ V) (Γ′ ▹ V)
extend θ (here x) = var (here x)
extend θ (there x) = there <$> θ x

_〉〉=_ : ∀ {Γ Γ′ : Type → Set} {t} → Term Γ t → Sub Γ Γ′ → Term Γ′ t
var x 〉〉= θ = θ x
〈〉 〉〉= θ = 〈〉
fun a 〉〉= θ = fun (a 〉〉= extend θ)
```

Comment: Looks good to me. The use of `_≡_ T` is one of things I was missing. Thanks!